# Add a object one level higher in pandas json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm new to json and pandas and want to output my data in the following schema, but I'm not sure how to add the leading 'results'.

My dataframe:

```
Name     Id    Qty   Value
thing1   123   10    12.5
thing2   456   20    15.4
thing3   789   40    84.2
```

My code:

```
json_output = df.reset_index().to_json(orient='record')
```

My Json output:

```
[{"id":456,
  "name":"thing2",
  "qty":20,
  "value":15.4
 },
 "id":123,
  "name":"thing1",
  "qty":10,
  "value":12.4
 },
  "id":789,
  "name":"thing3",
  "qty":40
  "value":84.2
 }
]
```

My Json schema that I want:

```
results:

     id:

     name:

     qty:

     value:
```

Comment: so `id:`, `name:`, etc. map on a *list* of values?

Comment: yeah so at the start of my list straight after the [ , I want "results":, then id: name: etc between curly brackets. like i already have. I just want the word "results" at the top of everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

tmp = [('thing1', 123, 10, 12.5),
            ('thing2', 456, 20, 15.4),
            ('thing3', 789, 40, 84.2),
            ]

df = pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns=['Name', 'Id','Qty', 'Value'], )
df_dict = df.to_dict(orient='records')
final_dict = {'results': df_dict}
json_output = json.dumps(final_dict)
```